# Google Sheets: Sum, Query, other Formulas Treating Values (Formatted as NUMBERS) as Zeroes in Formulas - Unclear why

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I have 15 Google Workbooks that import into 1 Workbook tab through an Importrange + Query combo function. The data is then queried and transformed across several other tabs, but the problem definitely begins on this tab.

Although I've manually forced a format change to "Number" in each workbook source AND in Columns CO:CQ (where the problematic data lands), all functions see the data as zero or null. Here is what happens when I set a random cell (CW33) equal to a cell in one of the trouble columns (CO33)
[image]

However, when I wrap the cell in an =sum(), the workbook returns "0":
[image]

I have no idea how to force the workbook to see the values in these rows as numbers without creating an entirely new column - does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it while preserving the column structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(CO33*1)
```

for multiple cells it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(CO33:CO34*1))
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CO33:CO34)
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in Sheets, a `Number` formatted cell displays contents *right-aligned* and `Plain-Text` are *left-aligned*. The highlighted cell looks like a text cell.

Try changing the format of cell or column manually to 'Number' from the 'Format' tab.